# a-asset-item loaded event (A-Frame 0.5.0)

Tags: aframe

I have the following assets:

```
<a-assets>
<a-asset-item id="model-obj" src="the-source..."></a-asset-item>
<a-asset-item id="model-mtl" src="another-source..."></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>
```

And after the scene is loaded I attached the following event listener which is never called and I don't know why (although the model loads and is shown in the scene):

```
document.querySelector('#model-obj').addEventListener('loaded', function() {
   console.log('loaded');
});
```

According to the docs it should work (https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/core/asset-management-system.html#lt-a-asset-item-gt).

Comment: The event to listen to is called 'model-loaded' and not 'loaded'. In general you have to listen on the entity which represents the model, not the asset!

Answer (score 0):

That's odd. This code works for me (but I'm using a glTF model):

```
<a-assets>
  <a-asset-item id="duck" src="duck/duck.gltf"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>
```

and
    document.getElementById('duck').addEventListener('loaded', function() {
      alert('ok')
    })

A few pointers:

- Is your script running after you've defined the element?
- Does the network inspector show you an unsuccessful load (HTTP 404, 500, etc.)?
- Any JS errors on your page in the console?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found the answer already by myself and added it as a comment to my question. I had to listen to the 'model-loaded' event.